# How to get a filled nested struct for PreviewProvider in SwiftUI

Tags: struct, nested, swiftui

how can I get some exampleData in my struct? I get example data at `SCode` very well, it works fine. But for `InstrNewOld` I don't get it. Any hints what I have to do?

I need this example data to get in SwiftUI the PreviewProvider working.

```
struct InstrNewOld: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var New: String
    var Old: String
    var SCode: [SCode]

    #if DEBUG
    static let exampleData = InstrNewOld(id: UUID(), New: "Testtext()", Old: "UILabel", SCode: SCode[])  //<- what is for SCode needed to get this example data?
    #endif
}

struct SCode: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var Zeile: String

    #if DEBUG
    static let exampleData = SCode(id: UUID(), Zeile: "Text as example")
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use example data as well

```
#if DEBUG
static let exampleData = InstrNewOld(id: UUID(), New: "Testtext()", 
                                     Old: "UILabel", SCode: [.exampleData])
#endif
```

Comment: If I try this, I get two error messages: ```Cannot use instance member 'SCode' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available``` and ```Value of type '[SCode]' has no member 'exampleData'```

Comment: @Enrico, updated. The error is because compiler confused by same names for `struct SCode` and `InstrNewOld.SCode`. That's bad practice, use capitalised type names and lowercased properties instead.